# How to define type in a array of context in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

I have a context:

```
export const templateContext = createContext({
  isButtonDisable: true,
  setIsButtonDisable: (p: boolean) => {},
  isSubmitReady: <boolean>false,
  setIsSubmitReady: () => {},
  buttonShow: false,
  handleButtonShow: (val: boolean) => {},
  steps:  [] ,
  handleSteps: (val: never) => {},
});
```

I am not understanding How can I define the type of array in this context. especially the **steps** array. That array also contains object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add a type for your object first, e.g.:

```
type MyContext = {
  isButtonDisable: boolean;
  setIsButtonDisable: (p: boolean) => {};
  // and so on //
  steps: String[];
};
```

If array is complex, you should create a separate type for it as well. For example, you array contains an array of `Step` objects:

```
type Step = {
  id: string;
  value: number;
};
```

So now you can modify your `MyContext`:

```
type MyContext = {
  isButtonDisable: boolean;
  setIsButtonDisable: (p: boolean) => {};
  // and so on //
  steps: Step[];
};
```

Comment: Yup do this and then set the generic when you create the context like createContext<MyContext>({